# JavaScript function execute only the first time

Tags: javascript, function, infowindow

I have this function and  it works fine the first time but when I try to execute it second time it doesn't work, why is that?

```
$("#miBoton").on('click', function() {
  var text = $("#myText").val();
  map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    if (text == feature.getProperty('SECTION')) {
      map.data.revertStyle();
      map.data.overrideStyle(feature, {
        strokeWeight: 8
      });
      var x = feature.getProperty("CX");
      var y = feature.getProperty("CY");
      var center = {
        lat: y,
        lng: x
      };
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        position: center
      });
      var contentString = '<div class="infoSection">' +
        '<div  class="iwTittle">' +
        '<h3 style="margin-top:0px!important; margin-bottom:0px!important; padding:0px;"> Seccion :' + feature.getProperty('SECTION') + '</h3>' +
        '</div>' +

        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        '<h4> Distrito :' + feature.getProperty('DLOCAL') + '</h4>' +
        '<iframe src="../window.php?section=' + feature.getProperty('SECTION') + '" style="width:100%; height:350px; border:0px"></iframe>'
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';
      infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
      infoWindow.open(map);
    }
  });
  var text = null;
});
```

Comment: map.data must not be same as earlier...

Comment: what did you mean with must not be same as earlier ? Im new at this sorry   Rayon

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? It doesn't run at all, or it runs but produces the wrong result?

Comment: doesn´t run the second time, I even tried  to debug  posting on console the variables but without any result